# How can i know when a JFrame is maximized state Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

Well, the question is simple. I want to know how can i know when a JFrame is maximized state in Java Swing.

I have tried to use this kind of function, but it just told me when the JFrame is Iconified, when is in normal state or maximized state, when i just want to know when is in maximized stated and just that.

```
private void formWindowStateChanged(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                        
        System.out.println(this.getState());
        if(this.getState()==1){//this means minimized
            System.out.println("Está minimizado");
        } else if(this.getState()==0){//this means maximized/normal state
            System.out.println("Está maximizado");
        }
    }
```

Any help? Thank you!

Comment: *"how can i know when a JFrame is maximized state"* ***Why*** do you think the code needs to know this condition? Layouts (correctly used) will change the size and position of components a frame contains. For custom painted components, a `repaint()` will be scheduled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the state of the JFrame at any point, you can use `frame.getExtendedState()`

If we implement this into the listener you have:

```
frame.addWindowStateListener(new WindowStateListener() {
    public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println(frame.getExtendedState());
        if(frame.getExtendedState() == Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH){
            System.out.println("The JFrame is maximised");
        }
    }
});
```

In a JFrame's fully maximised state, the `frame.getExtendedState()` function will return `Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH`.

Official Javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#getExtendedState()

Comment: Let's avoid using "magic numbers", numbers which have little intrinsic meaning by themselves. Instead use the contants that Java gives you, here `Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH`, which yes, equals 6, but is much more readable and stable to use.

Comment: I second the above comment. I would up vote except for the magic number used in the answer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels and camickr, good point about the answer. I have edited it according to your advice.